# Show div tag while click on Button

Tags: javascript, razor

While the page loads, the div tag below should be Hidden. The div should display when a button is clicked. I am using asp.net mvc razor

```
<div id="field">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.createSetting.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.createSetting.Name, new { @class = "span6 m-wrap" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.createSetting.Name)

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.createSetting.ExternalCode)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.createSetting.ExternalCode, new { @class = "span6 m-wrap"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.createSetting.ExternalCode)
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add Setting" id="btnAddSetting" class="btn green"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your div to be hidden initially:

```
<div id="field" style="display:none;">
```

Then using JQuery, add the click event to show the div:

```
<input onclick="javascript:$('#field').show();" .... />
```